# Windshield wipers freezing During Freezing Rain

Tags: car, winter

What is the best way to keep windshield wipers in ***good*** (*low ice build-up and ready to be used  but not a partial job because of above mentioned ice build-up*) working condition during a snow/freezing rain storm?   I have seen some people with them stuck out in the air. Other people have tried a towel over them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sticking them straight out works good in snow and ice rain, but is best when used with a towel, socks on the wipers or other waterproof cover. Ice getting into their joints stops them from working and can be a problem even if they are sticking straight out. Spraying something on the windshield works even better with this.

---

- White vinegar is suppose to limit the amount of ice that builds up, but I fail to see how this would be useful in vigorous rain. There are products built for this and if used liberally then they do work.
- This SE question gives some good feedback: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/5521/should-i-pull-my-wipers-away-from-the-windshield-when-parked-during-a-winter-sto#
- Putting a tarp over the car helps and there are pegs created to stop them from sticking to sticking to the window shield.